A question in the Page 98 from the book of " Riemannian Geometry, A Modern Introduction (by Chavel)"
My question is about the theme of mean curvature. I post the definition of mean curvature vector in the Page 98 from the book of " Riemannian Geometry, A Modern Introduction (by Chavel)" as follows.
The mean curvature vector $H$ of the submanifold $M$ at $p$ is given by
$$ H = \text{tr} \mathfrak{B},$$
where $\mathfrak{B}$  the second fundamental form, and the trace of $\mathfrak{B}$ is taken with respect to the Riemannian metric of $\overline{M}$ restricted to $M$, that is, the first fundamental form of $M$ in $\overline{M}$.
Thus,  if $\{\mathbf{e_1},\dots, \mathbf{e_n}\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $M_p$, then
$$ H = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathfrak{B}(\mathbf{e_j},\mathbf{e_j}) .$$
My question is How to understand why $H$ here is a vector？ In my sense, it is clearly scalar for $H$.
Although encountering such a elementary problem in reading a math book, one should learn to judge for oneself. But for a beginner, I'm really confused here. So thank you to the understanding person for providing an answer.

This question is similar to: Is there a notion of mean curvature for general submanifolds?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The second fundamental form is not a scalar, but rather has values in the normal bundle of the submanifold.

Thanks to Ted Shifrin for your kind answer.
